# Is it fine to use javascript sort instead of mongoose sort?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a messaging app, and a route to fetch a user's messages. A user can have 1000+ threads. I use Mongoose and Express.

I basically find a user by id, populate its messages array, and then apply a reverse() on it so it displays all the threads from new to old. I do it because I  don't know how to sort a populated field. Is it fine to use native js instead of mongoose sort method form a performance point of view?

```js
 const user = await User.findById({ _id: userId }).populate("messages");
    return res.json({ messages: user.messages.reverse() });
```

If it's crap, how to sort such a populated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to sort in order of creation you can use the `_id` field of each message. MongoDB treats sorting by `_id` the same as sorting by creation time. So your mongoose query would look like:

```
const user = await User
  .findById({ _id: userId })
  .populate({path: 'messages', options: { sort: { '_id': -1 } } });

return res.json({ messages: user.messages });
```

I am not quite sure as to the performance comparison of sorting using JS or Using mongoose though...

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it was possible to sort a populated query this way in mongoose!